# Does an Android app with device admin privilege require runtime permission requests?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, mobile

I wonder if I declare permissions like camera, location or storage access in manifest and later give app device admin permission would these permissions will automatically granted or should app ask for them during runtime?

Comment: Yes you still need to request permissions the same way you would otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Permissions in Android 6.0+ still suggest to ask for them during runtime, even with admin permission

You may can refer this [Docs](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/usage-notes).